# Remove space from start of variable in cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, character

Im making program that grabs ssid info, it works fine unless the ssid has a space between.

Ive tried removing the delim but this leaves a space at the front of the ssid and stops the rest of the program from functioning. 
I tried adding :~1 to the end but it adds it to the string

```
cd "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" & for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=:" %A in ('netsh wlan show interface ^| findstr "SSID" ^| findstr /v "BSSID"') do set A="%A":~1
netsh wlan show profiles %A% key=clear | findstr /c:"Network type" /c:"Authentication" /c:"Key Content" | findstr /v "broadcast" | findstr /v "Radio">>A.txt
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %A in ('findstr "Network type" A.txt') do set B=%A
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %A in ('findstr "Authentication" A.txt') do set C=%A
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %A in ('findstr "Key Content" A.txt') do set D=%A
```

For example if the ssid is "My House", I want that to be the output but instead it shows " My House"

Comment: `set A="%A":~1` can't work as sub-string expansion works only with normal environment variables but not with `for` variables; so I'd do `set "A=%A"` there and use `%A:~1%` instead of `%A%` in the next line... (perhaps it'd be a good idea to use a different variable name not to confuse `%A` and `%A%`...)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%A in ("...") do set A=%%A
echo."%A%"
```